# how to find whether the given number is a factorial of some number or not?

Tags: java, factorial

Tom teaches his student to find the factorial of a number.  He wanted to test the understanding of the student.  For that, he provides a number.  He wants the students to tell him that number is a factorial of which number.

Example : If Tom provides the number as 120, the student should answer as 5 because 5! = 120.

Help the student by writing a program to do this.  Note that the  input should be a number greater than zero.  If the input is less than or equal to zero, the output should be “Invalid Input”.  Also, if the input provided is not exactly the factorial of a number,  say, the input provided is 122, which is not a perfect factorial of a number, it should return “Sorry. The given number is not a perfect factorial”.

Sample Input 1 :
5040
Sample Output 1 :
7

Sample Input 2 :
0
Sample Output 2 :
Invalid Input

Sample Input 3 :
700
Sample Output 3 :
Sorry. The given number is not a perfect factorial

```
public static void main(string[] args){
Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
int n=sc.nextInt();
int m=n;
if (n<=0){
System.out.println("Invalid Input");
return;
}
for(int x=2;m!=x;x++)
{
m=m/x;
}
System.out.println(m);
}
else
System.out.println("the given number is not a perfect factorial")
}
```

while executing this program , it does not shows the expected result for non factorial numbers.like the sample output 3 i was not able to get it.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Please describe what problem you are facing. Also you might want to consider what happens when `n` is 1

Comment: Also kindly asking: Is this any kind of assigment?

Comment: Also you code is invalid: the `else` is missing its `if`

Comment: Sure this isn't a study assignment? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of compilation errors in your code.

I feel the simple and intuitive approach is to calculate the factorial starting from 1 until the factorial value exceeds input.while you calculate the factorial If the factorial value equals the the number you are checking, you found it. else its not a perfect factorial.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner( System.in );
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    if ( n <= 0 ) {
        System.out.println( "Invalid Input" );
        return;
    }
    int fact = 1;
    boolean found = false;
    int i = 2;
    for ( ; fact < n; i++ ) {
        fact *= i;
        if ( fact == n ) {
            System.out.println( i );
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if ( n == 1 ) {
        System.out.println( 1 );//handle edge case
        found = true;
    }
    if ( !found ) {
        System.out.println( "the given number is not a perfect factorial" );
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
We need to handle the edge case 1 separately. And it does not handle the integer overflow.

Comment: The absence of overflow handling leads to false positives and infinite loops in this code.

Comment: It is almost correct but the issue I am facing is,when the input value is 1 it shows "not a perfect factorial" which is  wrong  for that it should show like output 1, because 1 factorial is 1

Comment: this is not a complete answer. it does not handle 1 and it computes way too much. it should break out of loop if fact is greater than n

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner Added the edge case . And the loop will break when fact is greater than n in the for loop

Comment: The only thing it doesn't handle is the integer overflow.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your code even passes compilation (it looks like there's an else clause without a corresponding if in the end).

I'll focus on the error in your logic:

You are performing `int` division, dividing the input number by 2, 3, ..., n until the result of all these divisions becomes n, at which point you might reach the conclusion that the original input is factorial of n.

- first of all, you have no logic that would break out of the loop if the input is not a factorial. You should finish the loop if m <= x, and then say that the input is a factorial only if m == x.
- second of all, due to the int division, you might reach a false positive. For example, if you start with 7 and divide it by 2, you get 3. Then you find out that 3 is the next index of the loop, so you break out of the loop and reach the wrong conclusion that 7 is a factorial. You should perform the division only if `m % x == 0`. Otherwise, you know that the input is not a factorial, and you can break out of the loop.

Comment: or instead of division, s/he can simply multiply starting from 2. if the result passes the input, no factorial.

Comment: Except that you need to handle overflow carefully.